# Linker Error After Updating swift Version and pods

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, xcode8

I am installing Alamofire with pods and getting compile time error. There are a lot of questions regarding this but:

*Deleting the derived data & updating pods won't work for me.*

This is the error:

> Alamofire/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire compiled with newer version of Swift language (3.0) than previous files (2.0) for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please make in your mac machine having new updated pod version 1.1.0 at lease and also check inside Xcode project build setting > legacy = NO

Comment: I think that could be the reason. Let me check that.

Comment: Sure try for that because sometimes this thing happens, also faced this types of issue when migrating code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update following things in your pod files:**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3' || '3.0'
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It is still the same.

Comment: Add this one in your project settings manually.... ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the end of your pod file and run `pod install`:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Is your project fully converted to Swift 3 and Xcode 8?

Comment: Let me check that.

Answer (score 0):

**first remove your pods then clean derived data then -You can replace this on .podfile.**

```
platform :ios, '9.3'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'Meanwise' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix particular swift pod version:

Code snippet:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == '<insert target name of your pod here>'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'
            end
        end
    end
end
```