# Convert from Swift 3.0 to Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, converters

I have a static library that I converter from old Swift to Swift 2.3 and later to Swift 3.0.

Now I need both version (2.3 and 3.0) of the library, but I forgot to take a backup of version 2.3. And I only have 3.0.

Is there a simple way to convert back from Swift 3.0 to Swift 2.3?

Comment: I don't think so and you should use version control.

Comment: The only thing I think would work is if you have a backup using Swift 2.2 or less.

Comment: you can follow this link.... may be it helps you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859316/linker-error-after-updating-swift-version-and-pods/40859580#40859580

Answer (score 2):

Simple, not really, but this will work.

1. If you don't have it, download XCode 7.3.1 from Apple
2. Open your library in the 7.3.1 version and correct whatever errors appear
3. Migrate the corrected code from step 2 into XCode 8.2 or lower (8.3 will not support Swift 2.3)

As mentioned in the comments, maintaining your code in a version control system will spare you problems like this in the future, and is generally just a good idea.

You don't even need to set up your own system, since git is part of MacOS, and XCode can handle simple git features for you.

[image]